# Go to next quickfix entry, removing current?

Tags: quickfix

Is there a way to 'delete current, and cnext' so that when progressing through the quickfix list progress can more easily be seen, and, when all quick fixes have been made, the window automatically closes?

Comment: Also, `qa` works

Comment: True, I'll rephrase to remove that void 'use case'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the only way to update the quickfix list consists in manually changing its content with `setqflist()`.

With `getqflist({'idx': 'whatever'})` you should be able to obtain the index of the current item -- If I'm not mistaken you'll then have to count entries with `'nr'` field to use that index.

From here you should by now have an absolute index which you could use to clear the qflist before re-setting it.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't open the quickfix list in the first place. Both `:cnext` & `:cprev` give you information like `(1 of 10)`. And `:cc` will give you the current quickfix list information. You can use `:clist` to print out the list without opening a window.

You may need to look for `:cwindow` / `:copen` if the quickfix list is opening automatically or you copied part of your `vimrc` from someplace else.

For more help see:

```
:h quickfix
:h :cnext
:h :cc
:h :clist
:h :cwindow
:h :copen
```

Comment: This may be a good workaround for someone else, but it doesn't actually answer the question. In my main case the window is opened by a third-party plugin - I do the navigating, but not (explicitly) the window opening.

Comment: Do you want something like this? `command Cnext try | cnext | catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E553:/ | cclose | echo "End of quickfix list" | endtry`